# iOS 8 Simulator Back Button

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, ios8, xcode6

I just downloaded Xcode 6 to start testing my apps and the first thing I realized is when I have a statement that checks for a current user to go to the home screen, the back arrow still shows in the simulator after the new view is pushed. This does not happen on my device (iOS 7) when I compile with Xcode 6, just on all of the iPhone simulators. Here is my code, which was working perfectly on all simulators in Xcode 5.1:

```
if([PFUser currentUser])
    {
        self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
        self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;
        self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"tabFromLogin" sender:self];
    }
```

Is this an issue with the GM or do I need to add something in my code for iOS 8?